# Google like search string parsing to sql

Tags: postgresql, solr, lucene, indexing, full-text-search

Lets say I have a web application with a postgres database. I would like to add a google like search string(abc +  site:xyz + size>800 -pqrs) to it. So this string would generate a sql used to return results from the database. the table to search is basically a key value store with relational data. There could be different ways to do it.

Parsing/tokenizing the user query by myself and generating sql or use lucene or tsearch2 from postgresql. Not sure which one is a better approach yet. but i am inclined towards lucene.
If i use lucene, can i create the index in the db or will it reside on the file system? havent found any good tutorials for the latest version of lucene.

Can i use solr in the current web app or do i have to run it as a separate server instance and issue queries against it?
Some helpful links would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parsing/tokenizing the user query by myself and generating sql

In most cases this is ugly and error-prone, but in some circumstances not SO bad. If the database is relatively small and the schema is static, and there are not many fields (eg. columns) to search - this can be OK.

> or use lucene or tsearch2 from postgresql. Not sure which one is a better approach

In general, dedicated FTS is better.

Did you do the "homework" and spend some time on the Web? Please search "postgresql lucene" or "postgreSQL FTS" and read top 5 results. Start with this excellent presentation from Bill Karwin: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/full-text-search-in-postgresql

Which approach is better, this depends on many factors, including:

- Are you on J2EE or not?
- Do you want minimum maintenance or maximum performance?
- What is database usage pattern, beginning with Read/Write ratio?

> If i use lucene, can i create the index in the db or will it reside on the file system?

Most FTS solutions, including Lucene/Solr, use their own static index files *outside* of database. This is simply better for non-relational data.

> Can i use solr in the current web app or do i have to run it as a separate server instance and issue queries against it?

This is answered here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/#intro

Comment: yes parsing can be error prone, handling all corner cases can be quite a task. i am using GWT. i am looking for max performance. the writes dont happen too often.it is mostly read operations.